# Send value of input using a function

Tags: reactjs

My application get the data from a input and store it in the state. So, now, when i click on the `OK` button from the modal, i get the data in the console.
I want to do next thing: when i will click on `OK` button not only to save the data, but in the same time to send another data, using `Link` from react router. Something like this:

```js
<Link
    to={{
     pathname: `${my path}/demo}`,
    state: {my another data},
    }}
    >
  Send variable
</Link>
```

When i put the code above in

```js
    
const handleOk = e => {
    setState(false);
    return(
       <Link
        to={{
         pathname: `${my path}/demo}`,
        state: {my another data},
        }}
        >
      Send 
    )
     </Link>
};
```

How can i send the variable, through the `Link`, in my case, using `OK` button, and `handle ok` function?

my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-https-bnf3i

Answer (score 0):

Like this u can pass any value    `onOk={() => handleOk(event, "hello")}`

Comment: could you show me how the function will look? Because i can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: but where to insert this? :`<Link
        to={{
         pathname: `${my path}/demo}`,
        state: {my another data},
        }}
        >
      Send 
    )
     </Link>`

Comment: inside handleOk function. You can use the text value in Link on the place of my another data

Comment: i added, but it doesn't work. link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-https-bnf3i

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleOk = (e, text) => {
    setState(false);
    //thing you want to do with text
  };


<Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={visible}
        onOk={() => handleOk(event, "hello")}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <input onChange={input} />
      </Modal>
```